# SharePoint Lisa - Different groups of people with different views?

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know how to give different audience different views on the same sharepoint page? I am using sharepoint list (see attached screenshot). I hope that:

- When people from business 1 open the page, they see: Year Issued, Business 1, City, State.
- When people from business 2 open the page, they see: Year Issued, Business 2, City, State.

I guess its a target audience type of question and did basic google search. but cannot find a good way to do it. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Online google search

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the information look convenient, then you can create a corresponding view and let different companies choose the view that applies to them. But if you just want them to see a view that contains information about themselves, but not other company-related information, then this method will not work, and there is currently no OOTB method available. Because there is currently no permission setting for view.

Besides, I noticed that other community members have already raised their feedback about the same issue. You can vote and also encourage your team members to vote for this feature functionality. It would be ideal if there was a way to share a specific view to users! I have already added my vote via this link: [SharePoint Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/search/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472?q=how%20to%20share%20a%20list%20in%20a%20specific%20view). Microsoft values its customer feedback and a lot of features have been developed and suggested by customers via feedback. Your feedback is also very important. I am sure SharePoint List developers are work ing on this. Our Product Team is in-charge of the site and they are constantly checking the comments and feedback from our customers.